# How do I get MySQLi to return more detail about an error returned whilst processing a file of SQL queries?

Tags: php, mysqli

We have a method which initialises a test database as follows:

```
    $db=file_get_contents('test-data.sql');

    /* @var $result mysqli_result */
    $result=self::$_mysqlConn->multi_query($db);
    if (!$result) {
        fwrite(STDERR, self::$_mysqlConn->error."\nBUILD FAILED!\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    while ($nextResRes = self::$_mysqlConn->next_result()) {
        $tempRes = self::$_mysqlConn->store_result();
        if (!self::$_mysqlConn->more_results()) break;
    }

    if (self::$_mysqlConn->errno) {
        fwrite(STDERR, "DB QUERIES FAILED. FILE: ".$file."\n");
        fwrite(STDERR, self::$_mysqlConn->error."\nBUILD FAILED!\n");
        exit(1);
    }
```

The build is currently failing because of one of the queries in the data.sql file. The error being returned isn't very helpful:

```
DB QUERIES FAILED. FILE: data
Column count doesn't match value count at row 1
BUILD FAILED!
```

I'd like to somehow output the specific query which failed to `STDERR` at this point. How do I achieve this with MySQLi?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to split your multi-query string and run the queries individually. AFAIK there is no way to extract the query from MySQLi. You could obviously just split on `;` but that is potentially going cause errors (e.g. if one of your queries uses a string containing a `;`) and really you need to ensure that your `test-data.sql` file contains strings delimited by something that will never appear in a query.

One approach to this which should be safe is to split on `;\n` and ensure that all your queries are separated with new lines, and the a literal new line never appears *in* a query - essentially ensure you always use `\n` (which you should do anyway).

For example (*Note: I am not sure how or even if `store_result()` will work here - I have taken a best guess but this is untested and may need to be adapted)*:

*test-data.sql*:

```
INSERT INTO someTable
  (col1, col2, col3)
VALUES
  ('val1', 'val2', 'val3');

UPDATE someTable SET col1 = 'val' WHERE id = 4;

DELETE FROM someTable WHERE id > 7;
```

*PHP*:

```
// Get data from file and create an array of queries
$db = file_get_contents('test-data.sql');
$queries = explode(";\n", $db);

// Loop queries
foreach ($queries as $query) {

    // Trim whitespace and skip empty queries (mostly useful for last one)
    if (($query = trim($query)) === '') continue;

    // Do this query
    $result = self::$_mysqlConn->query($query);
    if (!$result) {
        fwrite(STDERR, self::$_mysqlConn->error."\nQuery: $query\nBUILD FAILED!\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    // Store result (?)
    self::$_mysqlConn->store_result();

    // This may not be the best place for this and it may not even be required
    // any more - that's a decision for you really
    if (self::$_mysqlConn->errno) {
        fwrite(STDERR, "DB QUERIES FAILED. FILE: ".$file."\n");
        exit(1);
    }

}
```

Comment: I guess I was hoping for something like a mysqli::getLastErrorQuery(), this works perfectly though.

Comment: Does the `store_result()` work like this? I have never tried to use it apart from in conjunction with `multi_query()` and I didn't have time to test it. I thought it probably should, but the docs don't say either way.

Comment: And thinking about it, you would be better splitting with `preg_split('/;\s*\n/')` in case there is any trailing whitespace after the query and before `\n`.